# Failure to restart after upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I am using a Lenovo W530 with a NVIDIA Quadro K1000M 2GB. Yesterday after upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 LTS, my laptop failed to restart. Specifically, it would get stuck at the splash screen with the 5 dots blinking under the Ubuntu logo. If I press the esc key and go to the diagnostic screen, I would see the last line saying

```
Starting CUPS printing spooler/server     [OK]
```

After looking at various suggestions (and following many of them without any difference) I finally suspected that it could be because of the NVIDIA drivers and tried to boot it using the nomodeset. That did not solve the problem except that the last few lines in the diagnostic screen now says

```
Starting Mount network filesystems    [OK]  
Stopping Mount network filesystems    [OK]  
Stopping LightDM Display Manager      [OK]  
Starting CUPS printing spooler/server [OK]  
Starting Mount network filesystems    [OK]  
Stopping Mount network filesystems    [OK]  
Starting Mount network filesystems    [OK]  
Stopping Mount network filesystems    [OK]
```

Sorry, I don't know much about linux and any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mine halts during boot at:
    * Stopping Samba Auto-reload Integration [OK]

I don't know how I can modify the smb files from this post (http://askubuntu.com/questions/450109/when-attempting-upgrade-from-13-10-to-14-04-upgrade-halted-at-aborting-samba-li), I really just use this as a desktop machine and have work to do :(

Comment: how long did you wait? it can take up to 120 seconds to pass failsafe boot if you have no network which may seem like an eternity. Maybe give it some time and then check the contents of /etc/network/interfaces to make sure you don't have an entry for "auto eth0" or something else like that. "auto lo" and "iface lo inet loopback" are all okay.

Comment: @mchid I waited for quite sometime (more than 10 minutes) and still nothing happens. I think the problem is related to the one here http://askubuntu.com/questions/74551/lightdm-not-starting-on-boot because I finally managed to login through a tty and running sudo start lightdm

Comment: Yes. Changing lightdm to usr/sbin/lightdm in the default-display-manager file in the folder /etc/X11 did work, at least for the moment.

Comment: You can submit and accept your own answer if that works to close it out.